# Performance hit when converting IEnumerable to List of Tasks

Tags: c#, performance, linq, asynchronous, ienumerable

```cs
public async Task<List<usp_TeamMeetingGetAll_Result>> TeamsMeetingReportGetAll(bool activeOnly)
{
    List<usp_TeamMeetingGetAll_Result> teamMeetingGetAllResults = _db
      .usp_TeamMeetingGetAll(activeOnly)
      .ToList();

    IEnumerable<Task<usp_TeamMeetingGetAll_Result>> taskListQuery = 
      from teamMeetingGetAllResult in teamMeetingGetAllResults 
      select TeamsMeetingGet(teamMeetingGetAllResult);
      
    List<Task<usp_TeamMeetingGetAll_Result>> taskList = taskListQuery.ToList();

    usp_TeamMeetingGetAll_Result[] results = await Task.WhenAll(taskList);

    return results.OrderBy(r => r.DisplayStartDate).ToList();
}
```

I'm trying to figure out why line 3 (the taskList assignment) takes 7-8 seconds to execute.  Line 1 calls a stored proc and puts the results (26 rows, about 15 columns) in a list and takes about 1.5 seconds.  Line 2 takes less than a millisecond.  Line 4 takes about 4 seconds for all async tasks to complete.

Edit: Okay, thanks to the answers below I understand that:
`List<Task<usp_TeamMeetingGetAll_Result>> taskList = taskListQuery.ToList();`
is causing calls to TeamsMeetingGet.  I should have checked that before.

TeamsMeetingGet is making a aync call to a web API, waiting for the results, populating some properties of the usp_TeamMeetingGetAll_Result object with the results, and passing it back.

```cs
        public async Task<usp_TeamMeetingGetAll_Result> TeamsMeetingGet(usp_TeamMeetingGetAll_Result teamMeetingGetAllResult)
        {
            //OnlineMeeting onlineMeeting = await TeamsMeetingGet(teamMeetingGetAllResult.JoinWebUrl);
            HttpClient client = GraphHelper.GetAuthenticatedHttpClient();
            
            string request =
                    "users/xxxxxxxxxx/onlineMeetings?$filter=JoinWebUrl%20eq%20'" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(teamMeetingGetAllResult.JoinWebUrl) + "'";

            var response = await client.GetAsync(request);
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var jresult = JObject.Parse(result);
            
            var onlineMeetings = jresult["value"].ToObject<OnlineMeeting[]>();
            
            if (onlineMeetings[0].Id != null)
            {
                teamMeetingGetAllResult.NumAttendees = onlineMeetings[0].Participants.Attendees.Count();
                teamMeetingGetAllResult.Subject = onlineMeetings[0].Subject;
                //More assignments
            }
            else
            {
                teamMeetingGetAllResult.NumAttendees = 0;
                teamMeetingGetAllResult.Subject = "";
            }

            return teamMeetingGetAllResult;
        }
```

If I have 100 rows, I'd like to call TeamsMeetingGet 100 times simultaneously, instead of synchronously. Is this how I do it?

I asked for the GetAuthenticatedHttpClient code and got back:

```cs
    public class GraphHelper
    {
        private static string _graphClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["graphClientSecret"];
        private static string _graphClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["graphClientId"];
        private static string _graphTenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["graphTenantId"];

        public static HttpClient GetAuthenticatedHttpClient()
        {
            IConfidentialClientApplication app;
            var clientId = _graphClientId;
            var tenantID = _graphTenantId;

            app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
                .WithClientSecret(_graphClientSecret)
                .WithAuthority(new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantID))
                .Build();

            string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

            AuthenticationResult result = null;
            try
            {
                result = app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
                    .ExecuteAsync().Result;
            }
            catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
            {
                // The application doesn't have sufficient permissions.
                // - Did you declare enough app permissions during app creation?
                // - Did the tenant admin grant permissions to the application?
                throw ex;
            }
            catch (MsalServiceException ex) when (ex.Message.Contains("AADSTS70011"))
            {
                // Invalid scope. The scope has to be in the form "https://resourceurl/.default"
                // Mitigation: Change the scope to be as expected.
                throw ex;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", result.AccessToken);
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/");
            return client;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The delay is caused by `TeamsMeetingGet`. What does this method do? Iterating a 26-item list takes only micro- if not nanoseconds. In this case each call to `TeamsMeetingGet` takes > 300ms.

Comment: Just to confirm - you do understand that "line 2" does not execute anything? It is possible you are asking "why LINQ queries are lazy executed" (or something like that)... Some [edit] with clarification of that would improve the question (along with adding [mre]).

Comment: Could you include the `TeamsMeetingGet` method in the question?

Comment: What does `GraphHelper.GetAuthenticatedHttpClient();` do? That's not an async call. If `GraphHelper` refers to Microsoft Graph that may be an expensive HTTP call or calls that could easily take 300ms. If the method uses object pooling or locking incorrectly, instead of providing a few reusable clients to the tasks it will end up creating one client per task. If locking is used that may well be done sequentially

Comment: Could you replace the `TeamsMeetingGet(teamMeetingGetAllResult)` with `Task.Run(() => TeamsMeetingGet(teamMeetingGetAllResult))`, and see if it makes any difference?

Comment: As a side note, the `HttpClient` class is intended to be instantiated [once](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client#create-and-initialize-httpclient), and reused throughout the life of an application.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Thank you! Task.Run seems to do exactly what I want.  As to HttpClient, does the same go for a webapi project? This is a .NET Framework API project which calls other APIs from various companies.

Comment: NeilN the `Task.Run` was suggested for troubleshooting, not as a fix. Using it in a WebAPI project can cause `ThreadPool` saturation pretty easily. You should really investigate which part of the **a**synchronous method `TeamsMeetingGet` blocks the current thread.